# Can I get cookies by js and send it to another url which is in different domain by jsonp or any other requests?

Tags: javascript, cookies, jsonp

I am learning the basic knowledge of Same-Origin-Policy and cross-site-request. 
The question is can I get cookies for current domain and send them to another domain by jsonp ?

For example, there are two websites. `www.A.com` and `www.B.com`.

If user login to `A`, there are some cookies in user's browser for `A`. We know   that we cannot send XHR to B with cookies because of the restriction of Same-Origin-Policy. But can we get the cookies using `js` and send them as parameters using `jsonp`.

such as:

`<script>http://www.B.com/xxx?cookies=REALCOOKIES` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am reading this right, this is essentially how Google Analytics cross-domain tracking works. When a user clicks on a link to another domain, the cookie values are appended onto the querystring for the link which are then picked up on the other end and then turned back into a cookie (or whatever it is you want to do with it).

If you are talking about reading cookies from one domain to the other, you can do this server-side IF you have some sort of asset request that is available to both domains e.g. an image. This is (in essence) how affiliate, media banner, facebook tracking works, i.e. the concept of ads "following" you around while you are surfing (do people still surf?) the internet.

If you are the developer for both domains you could also write an api (server-side) that makes a request to domain www.A.com and retrieves the required cookies.

Comment: Thank @Jarrod a lot for your detailed explanation in different aspects. Actually I just want to know whether we can send the essential cookies such as `session-id` to another domain. I just knew that server can set a cookie to `httpOnly` to prevent it being retrieved from client side by `js` code. Thus, these cookies cannot be sent to another domain. Anyway, thanks for your answers